# Python tkinter main window bind mouse over/leave triggering while still inside main window

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x, graphics, tkinter

I have a main window - `root`.

Within it I have a main label image at the top, and then some buttons underneath, the buttons change their images (animate) when mouse goes over them, but the main label image does so when mouse enters the main window altogether, and revert to off image when mouse leaves the app.

This is working just fine to a point.

When I move my mouse from main image to a button, or from a button to a button the program seems to think that I've actually left, and then re-entered the main window, which is clearly not the case. This malfunction causes the program to re-animate the main label each time this happens (which is often), thus producing an ugly-looking gui.

My theory is that the space between the buttons (1px wide for idk what reason it is there, but I can't get it to go away...) is actually read by the program as not being a piece of the main window, thus causing this problem.

[Image with details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NX2ms.jpg)

```
#Python 3.4.3 on Win7 x64
def startApp (): #initializes crucial tkinter gui components
    global root
    root = Tk()
    root.configure(bg="white")
    root.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)
    #******
    root.bind ("<Enter>", turnMainImageOn1)
    root.bind("<Leave>", turnMainImageOff)
    #******
    drawMainWindow()
    root.mainloop()
```

main label image def:

```
mainImageOff = PhotoImage(file="Resources/Main/mainImageOff.png") #main window logo image
    mainImageLabel = Label(root, image=mainImageOff, bd=0, bg="white")
    mainImageLabel.image = mainImageOff
    mainImageLabel.pack(side=TOP)
```

and then the animation functions themselves:

```
def turnMainImageOn1 (event): #main image on animation frame 1
    mainImageOn1 = PhotoImage(file="Resources/Main/mainImageOn_1.png")
    mainImageLabel.configure(image=mainImageOn1)
    mainImageLabel.image = mainImageOn1
    root.after(17, turnMainImageOn2)

def turnMainImageOn2 (): #main image on animation frame 2
    mainImageOn2 = PhotoImage(file="Resources/Main/mainImageOn_2.png")
    mainImageLabel.configure(image=mainImageOn2)
    mainImageLabel.image = mainImageOn2
    root.after(17, turnMainImageOn3)

def turnMainImageOn3 (): #main image on animation frame 3
    mainImageOn3 = PhotoImage(file="Resources/Main/mainImageOn_3.png")
    mainImageLabel.configure(image=mainImageOn3)
    mainImageLabel.image = mainImageOn3

def turnMainImageOff (event): #sets main image to off
    mainImageOff = PhotoImage(file="Resources/Main/mainImageOff.png")
    mainImageLabel.configure(image=mainImageOff)
    mainImageLabel.image = mainImageOff
```

I'm new to programming, so please bear with me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like calling `bind` on the root Toplevel object, also causes each child object of the root to be bound. So `turnMainImageOff` will trigger whenever the cursor leaves *any* widget, not just the main window.

One possible solution is to inspect the event object to determine which widget triggered the event. You can then return early for any widget other than the root.

```
def turnMainImageOn1 (event):
    if event.widget != root:
        return
    #rest of function goes here

#...

def turnMainImageOff (event): #sets main image to off
    if event.widget != root:
        return
    #rest of function goes here
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks!
Do you by any  chance know why I have these white 1px spaces between my buttons, even though all bd=0 ? See the linked image for clarity. :)

Comment: Are you sure the images themselves don't have white borders? When I pack image labels on my machine, there's no gap.

Comment: Yes, they are borderless. It's worth mentioning that root bg is redish color, while button bg is white, which I think points to the conclusion that it's the buttons' bg showing, even though bd = 0 and images are borderless too.
Since my main label doesn't have that ugly white spacing (compared at the left sides of widgets) this seems to be a button-specific issue.
Besides, what machine did you run it on? May be it's system specific...

Comment: Oh, I thought they were labels, not buttons. Yeah, I have a white border too. I guess that's just how buttons are. I suppose you could change them to Labels without losing any functionality...